# Явный вызов конструктора для объекта

Tags: c++, malloc

Как создать объект в динамической памяти используя malloc()? Нужно ведь явно вызывать конструктор, как это сделать?

Comment: new (ptr) Type(/*params*/);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вам нужен placement new.

Например, так:

```
void* place = malloc(sizeof(Object));
Object* o = new(place) Object();
```

Не забудьте в конце вызвать и деструктор вручную:

```
o->~Object();
```

и если нужно

```
free(place);
```

Документация:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

---

Для случая, когда у вас память выделена заранее, вам придётся позаботиться о выравнивании. Обычный указатель, который возвращает `malloc`, имеет выравнивание, достаточное для нормально объявленного класса, то есть, класса, определение которого не содержит `alignas()` (а также определение классов его полей), и значит, ничего больше делать не нужно.

Если это (отсутствие `alignas`) не гарантировано, у вас есть два пути. Вы можете вместо `malloc` использовать `aligned_alloc` (или [`_aligned_malloc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc) на старых версиях Visual Studio), который выдаёт `malloc` с нужным выравниванием:

```
void* place = std::aligned_alloc(alignof(Object), sizeof(Object));
void* place = _aligned_malloc(sizeof(Object), alignof(Object));
```

(да, порядок противоположный).

Или если вам нужен именно `malloc`, то можно заказать больше памяти для того, чтобы было место для выравнивания, и выровнять указатель при помощи [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align):

```
std::size_t alloc_size = sizeof(Object) + alignof(Object) - 1;
void* place = malloc(alloc_size);
void* aligned_place = place;
if (std::align(alignof(Object), sizeof(Object), aligned_place, alloc_size))
{
    Object* o = new(aligned_place) Object();
    // ...
}
```

Эта вторая техника пригодится, если вы захотите выделить в одном буфере несколько объектов.

Comment: @Abyx: Хорошо подмечено. Нет, гарантии нет, конечно. Выравнивать вручную не очень комильфо. Впрочем, пример из C++ FAQ делает то же самое :-/

Comment: The `malloc()` and `calloc()` functions return a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned **for any kind of variable**. — из [ответа на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752616/2553424) «How does malloc understand alignment?»

Comment: @Arhad: Ого, а вот этого не знал, спасибо.

Comment: @Abyx: Хм, я допишу код для случая диких требований по выравниванию (вечером).

Comment: Ать - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html два - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8z34s9c6.aspx

Comment: Тогда уже http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc

Comment: @Abyx: Вроде ничего не пропустил?